# PySpark.Join or union DataFrame and keep order?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframe.
First dataframe contains stages and value, stages which needs to be correlated.

```
+-------+-----+
| stages|value|
+-------+-----+
|Stage_0|    A|
|Stage_3|    B|
|Stage_5|    C|
|Stage_2|    D|
|Stage_7|    E|
|Stage_4|    F|
|Stage_8|    G|
|Stage_9|    H|
|Stage_6|    I|
|Stage_1|    J|
+-------+-----+
```

Second dataframe

```
+---+-------+
| id| stages|
+---+-------+
|0.0|Stage_0|
|0.0|Stage_3|
|0.0|Stage_5|
|0.0|Stage_2|
|0.0|Stage_7|
|1.0|Stage_0|
|1.0|Stage_2|
|1.0|Stage_4|
|1.0|Stage_3|
|1.0|Stage_8|
|2.0|Stage_0|
|2.0|Stage_2|
|2.0|Stage_3|
|2.0|Stage_4|
|2.0|Stage_5|
|2.0|Stage_8|
|2.0|Stage_7|
|3.0|Stage_2|
|3.0|Stage_9|
+---+-------+
```

The second dataframe contains stages and id. You need to correlate Stages from the first and second Dataframe.
I want to combine two frames and get:

```
         id   stages   symbol
0       0.0  Stage_0     A
1       0.0  Stage_3     B
2       0.0  Stage_5     C
3       0.0  Stage_2     D
4       0.0  Stage_7     E
5       1.0  Stage_0     A
6       1.0  Stage_2     D
7       1.0  Stage_4     F
8       1.0  Stage_3     B
9       1.0  Stage_8     G
10     10.0  Stage_0     A
11     10.0  Stage_2     D
12     10.0  Stage_5     C
13     10.0  Stage_7     E
14    100.0  Stage_2     D
15    100.0  Stage_3     B
```

I use join, but order is changes.
I want save order and union dataframes.

What can I do?

Comment: Join operation shuffles the data so preserving order is not possible, in my opinion. Regarding union, I would not count on that as well. What I would do is `sort` after the union or join. Off course, it impacts performance as sorting could be expensive. `df.union(df2).sort('id','stage')`.

Answer (score 0):

Join will shuffle your data, so the only way to reserve your order (assuming based on `id` column) is using sort`

```py
df.join(df2, on=['stages']).orderBy('id')
```